# How to schedule auto-exporting MS Access query to Excel and email it?

Tags: email, ms-access-2010, export-to-excel, schedule

I know Access can setup an Outlook Task to auto-export query to Excel, but it requires the Outlook to be always open on the user's computer.

Is there an easy way to setup a schedule that can automatically export a query to Excel and this schedule will then auto-email the exported Excel file to an email address every Monday at 5AM for example?

If this can only be done in VBA, any reference I may start with?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this with Access. You can use a tool like these:

http://www.r-tag.com

http://www.hybing.com/Report-Genie.html

They are able to get data from a database, export it to excel and email it. Report genie is cheap although it is pretty old software and I don't know if it has any support. I don't think there is a way to schedule tasks too. R-Tag has paid and free version. Both versions will allow you to schedule a task to export data from any database to excel and email the file. There are some restrictions for the free version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to schedule it, but this may give you a good start:

```
If Weekday(Now(), 2) = 1 Then   
If Forms![Head Form]![Once subform].Form![ID] = 0 Then
DoCmd.OpenQuery "UpdateOnce1", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenReport "Report1", acViewPreview
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export-Report 1"

Dim strSql
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
Dim Outlook
Dim rng
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
.To = "number of mail adresses"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Report 1"
.HTMLBody = ""
.Attachments.Add ("T:\.....\Report1.pdf")
.Send

End With


DoCmd.Close acReport, "Report1"

End If
End If
```

So if it is monday, and the code hasn't run yet (it checks if the ID equals 0), Report 1 is openend, exported to PDF, added as an attachment and then mailed via outlook.